# Cálculo de porcentagem PHP e salvar no Banco

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer um cálculo antes de enviar pro Banco de Dados:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once 'config/init.php';
require 'config/check.php';
?>

<?php

require 'config/conexao.php';

try {
    $PDO = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . MYSQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . MYSQL_DB_NAME, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8' ) );
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    echo 'Erro ao conectar com o MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$descricao          = $_POST ['descricao'];
$fornecedor         = $_POST ['fornecedor'];
$custo              = $_POST ['custo'];
$margemlucro        = $_POST ['margemlucro'];
$estoque            = $_POST ['estoque'];

$custo1 = $_POST ['custo'];
$margemlucro1 = $_POST ['margemlucro'];
$precofinal = $custo1 + ($custo1 / 100 * $margemlucro1);

$sql = "INSERT INTO produtosservicos (descricao, fornecedor, custo, margemlucro, precofinal, estoque) VALUES
                                     (:descricao, :fornecedor, :custo, :margemlucro, :precofinal, :estoque)";

$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':descricao', $_POST['descricao'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':fornecedor', $_POST['fornecedor'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':custo', $_POST['custo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':margemlucro', $_POST['margemlucro'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':precofinal', $precofinal);
$stmt->bindParam(':estoque', $_POST['estoque'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute($stmt);

echo "<script>alert('Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!'); window.top.location.href = 'produtos-servicos.php';</script>";

?>
```

O cálculo ocorre, mas não salva no banco e nem dá erro. O que posso estar fazendo de errado? Se eu tiro o campo do cálculo, ele salva normalmente. Já troquei no banco para `int`, `decimal` e por fim deixei mesmo como `varchar`.

Atualização: Encontrei o erro `[28-Jan-2019 18:03:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in ******* on line 39`
. Ainda não resolvi o problema.

Comment: `$stmt->execute()` retornou `true`?

Comment: `expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in...` o código estava mandando pra index automático, não tinha visto o erro.

Comment: Pelo que to vendo, tu ta passando tudo como string no banco, este é um valor que nem sequer precisa ser armazenado, ele pode ser calculado pelo banco no retorno

Comment: Pensei em dar a opção de mudança, caso necessário. Por isso, to armazenando tudo. O que me recomenda, @bruno101 ?

Comment: Tem gente que tem prazer em dar downvote, não entendo...

Comment: Negativaram provavelmente porque sua pergunta não é clara. Você achou o erro, mas ainda não adicionou na pergunta. Você até colocou nos comentários a mensagem, mas omitiu as partes mais importantes: nome do arquivo e linha do erro. Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar todos os detalhes que possui do problema até agora?

Comment: Feito, @AndersonCarlosWoss.

Comment: E novamente você **omitiu** informações do erro como acabei de comentar. Você tem certeza que colocou na pergunta exatamente o trecho que possui o erro? Pergunto porque o erro claramente está reclamando que você passou um objeto como parâmetro para `PDOStatement::execute()`, mas no trecho que colocou na pergunta nem parâmetro tem nesta chamada.

Comment: Editei novamente a pergunta, tentando não omitir nenhum tipo de informação, peço por gentileza que avalie. Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo ler novamente as documentações das funções que está utilizando: [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php), [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

O método `PDOStatement::execute()` espera um parâmetro do tipo `array`, que é opcional, mas você passa como parâmetro `$stmt`. Você basicamente chamou um método do objeto e passou ele mesmo como parâmetro - isso dificilmente fará sentido.

Como já atribuiu os valores com `bindParam`, não precisa passar parâmetros para o `execute`:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Lendo a documentação verá que o método possui retorno. Não o ignore.

Comment: A sua informação foi útil e resolveu meu problema. Por fim, gostaria de colocar o código final, para informação. Como devo proceder?

Comment: @CyberPlague Não necessita, basta sinalizar como útil a resposta utilizando o **✓**

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio. Só lamento pela minha falta de compreensão no desenvolvimento da questão, fico triste pelo downvote. Espero acertar estas questões. Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->bindParam(':precofinal', $_POST['precofinal'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Tu não tem um `$_POST['precofinal']`.
Aconselho a trocar os valores do banco, deixar tudo como string não é uma boa pratica, este valor, por exemplo, poderia ser calculado e retornado pelo próprio banco e n~;ao pela aplicação.

Comment: Tens alguma referência para estudo, por favor? O $_POST passou mesmo, acabei não vendo, mas mesmo corrigindo, o erro persiste.